# pyparsing: Using '\n' as a delimiter in delimitedList()

Tags: python, pyparsing

x1 is a string from a file which contains letters followed by a new line like this:

a
b
c
d
e

```
newl=Word(alphas)
newl1 = delimitedList(newl,White('\n'))
newl1.parseString(x1)
```

I would expect this to return: ['a','b','c',...]
what it actually returns is: ['a']

My question becomes, is my syntax correct and is there a better way to parse new lines as delimiters using pyparsing.

Edit: thanks for reminding me, it is python 2.7.8

Comment: I can't reproduce this, i.e. I'm getting all characters. `x1 = 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n'` parses to: `(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], {})`.

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: I get same results as @BlackJack. But in general, if you have one or more of something that is just separated by whitespace, then just use `OneOrMore(something_expression)` - the whitespace will be skipped by default.